# Export file using image saved to memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, charts, memorystream

I am wanting to save an image to file which has been stored in a memory stream.

I have saved a asp.net chart to a memory stream.

```
stream1 = new MemoryStream();
chart_location_3.SaveImage(stream1, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

and i am then using the following code to export to a jpg. It triggers the save to prompt and creates the file but the image will not open ("this is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported")

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

System.Drawing.Image img;

img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream1);
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= Exported.jpg;");
response.Write(img);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changed the response write to:

```
response.BinaryWrite(stream1.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this before:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

It generates image to browser on the fly.  Hope it helps.

---

As per the answer at dotnetperls, it is using response.binarywrite.  Change code as below:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

System.Drawing.Image img;

img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream1);
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= Exported.jpg;");
response.BinaryWrite(img);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: Maybe try Response.BinaryWrite instead of Response.Write

Answer (score 0):

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStatChart()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        var chartImage = new Chart(600, 400);
        chartImage.AddTitle("Chart Title");
        chartImage.AddSeries(
                name: "Employee",
                chartType: "Pie",
                axisLabel: "Name",
                xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
                yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" });
        byte[] chartBytes = chartImage.GetBytes();

        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(chartBytes);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

        return response;



    }
```

Comment: Using the Web API 2 and <img src="">